# Get real height size of a cell from UITableViewCell

Tags: xcode, swift, uitableview

On a custom UITableViewCell, what are the best location to have the real(custom) height of a cell.

I've try

```
 override func awakeFromNib() {
        btnIsFav.center.y = self.center.y
```

But look like awakeFromNib are called to soon to have the real info of the custom height.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `layoutSubviews`. that's when the cell begins to initialize its subviews